# Writing to HTML through Python without import os? (Python 3.8 / Windows)

Tags: python, html, user-input

Basically, what I want to know is, is there a simpler way to write this that does not require the `import os` module?
I want to create a simple webpage from Python using an HTML file. And while this does exactly what I want, I cannot seem to come up with a simple/basic way, or a way that does not involve the `import os` module.

```
import os

name = input("Enter your name here: ")
persona = input("Write a sentence or two describing yourself: ")

with open('mypage.html', 'rt') as file:
    with open('temp_mypage.html', 'wt') as new:
        for line in file:
            line = line.replace('some_name', name)
            line = line.replace('some_persona', persona)
            new.write(line)

os.remove('mypage.html')
os.rename('temp_mypage.html', 'mypage.html')
```

HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<center>
<h1>
some_name
# input into the file
</h1>
</center>
<hr />
some_persona
<hr />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use Flask:
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/

Comment: Secondly, why would you want to do that

Comment: Because I did not realize that my instructor did not want us to use import os and now I am trying to figure out how to rewrite it.

Comment: Oh so its homework

Comment: I have something to do with that

Comment: Yeah, homework. I hate to complain and come seek help, but the instructor herself just doesn't want to help me or my class. Its always "I don't know what to tell you" from her so here I am..

Comment: oh well oof man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need os module and temporary file, instead you can just add to a variable and write back

```
name = input("Enter your name here: ")
persona = input("Write a sentence or two describing yourself: ")
new = ""

with open('mypage.html', 'rt') as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.replace('some_name', name)
            line = line.replace('some_persona', persona)
            new += line.strip()

with open('mypage.html','w') as f:
        f.write(new)
```

And for tasks like this it is not the recommended way. Use a web framework like Flask (Django will be top heavy for this simple one), CGI scripts are now outdated

Comment: Oh... thats what he wanted. Well, I thought he was to activate the website to a web page or something. I am a dumb boi

Comment: Ah, I see, this works really well! Before I uploaded the working code, I was trying to open it in writer mode with the "for line" statement, but it kept telling me it was not a readable object and that threw me off. For the most part this makes sense, and it does work, can you possibly explain the ' new = "" ' line to me please?

Comment: `new=""` creates a new empty string variable and also to both read/write from a file open in `rw` mode, please upvote (click ^ looking button) and accept (click big check mark), welcome :-)

Comment: Oh okay, alright now I understand it a lot better. This was an amazing fix! Thanks man! I appreciate it

Comment: @WasifHasan  I did not to think to ask before, and I hope it is not a bother, but is it possible to loop this program? And what I mean by that is, how can I run the program over and over without ceating a new html file every time, because as a test run, I entered JK as the input in both fields and now my html file is permanently set to JK. If that makes sense. I am unsure of how to google this question..

Comment: But it does not create a new html file, modifies the existing one

Comment: Sorry, that is what I meant. I want to modify the html file except that it does not modify it. It just keeps the same input